# webpack sass to css files in Production with mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, webpack-4

New to webpack & node. I try to figure out, how to get huge SCSS files into CSS files for production and then link them to the output files. Sitting here for hours and in development mode everything is fine. When I run my build script, then the CSS files are built perfectly fine with hashes in filenames. But in production, there is no relation to my HTML files. (In dev it works great).

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = (env, argv) => {  
    const devMode = argv.mode !== 'production' 
    return {
        entry: {
            index: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/scripts/index.js'],
            edit: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/scripts/edit.js'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
            filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {loader:  'css-loader', options: {importLoaders: 2} },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                  ],
            }
            ]
        },
         devServer: {
            contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
            publicPath: '/scripts/'
        },
            devtool: 'source-map',
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: devMode ? '../styles/[name].css' : '../styles/[name].[hash].css',
                    chunkFilename: devMode ? '../styles/[id].css' : '../styles/[id].[hash].css',
            })
        ]
    }
}
```

In my page-js files, I Import my SCSS

```
import '../styles/styles.scss'
```

Which seems to have no effect in production but works fine in dev.

After hours of research, my only idea would be to set manually a link tag in the HTML files...

I am very new to webpack, so every help is highly appreciated. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any CSS-related output from the production build that you could share?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I am not sure if i got you right... . There are perfectly fine css files in my production build, which I can relate with link tag in my html. This is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was asking if you were able to get any webpack-related output (errors or warnings) when you passed the --verbose or --display-error-details CLI switches